# Can you rename your team in Dragon Quest IX?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

When I first played DQ9, probably a decade ago, I had Patty give me random party members. They had pretty good names. Eventually, I got bored and stopped playing. When I started playing again (still a good deal of years ago) I decided to restart the game. When I did this, I selected the character’s names, and I gave them pretty stupid names. I can hardly bear to play anymore, because every time I play I think of what the characters’ names *should* be instead of the dumb names they have. Is there any way to rename them?

Restarting the game is not an option, there’s no way I’m redoing 72 hours of gameplay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no rename option. If you do not want to start over (which I understand) you are bound to the names given to the characters.